# What is difference between references created from a class,this way in C#

Tags: c#

```
class ref1 = new class();
class ref2 = ref1;
```

What is difference between `ref1` and `ref2` in C# ?

Comment: Nothing. They're the same and point to the same object.

Comment: nothing , they are objects for the same class ....

Comment: Here specifically there is a compilation error

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates a class and passes the reference to the class as value to your variable ref1. Your variable is a value and the value will contain the reference to the object.

In the second example, you create a new variable and pass onto it the value of the reference of the first variable.

In short, both variables will hold the reference to the same object when you assign then via

```
ClassName ref2 =  ref1;
```

To you, they will be the same instance. You change a value in ref1, it will also change in ref2 and vice versa.

So, if you want two different objects, then you should assign them like this:

```
ClassName ref1 = new ClassName();
ClassName ref2 = new ClassName();
```

The new keyword will create a new object for you in memory.

Comment: Oops you're right, I'm gonna edit that real quick. I just kinda ignored the class keyword...

Answer (score 0):

In this case ref1 and ref2 are pointers referring to the same object.

Ex: if you modify a property of ref2, it will affect ref1.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are describing the  ref1 and ref 2 are the same at creation and are both pointing to the same ojbect by reference, meaning if you use `ref1` to change something, these changes are also visible in `ref2` since this object is just pointing to `ref1`
[This article should give the full story](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same pointer. Changes in ref1 will be visible in ref2. Take a look on this:

http://csharppad.com/gist/ce30f0ae1a1d73bdf3ceec9e1e30b0cf

And code for this:

```
class test {
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
var ref1 = new test {
    IntProperty = 12
};
var ref2 = ref1;
Console.WriteLine(ref1.IntProperty);
Console.WriteLine(ref2.IntProperty);
ref1.IntProperty = 15;
Console.WriteLine(ref1.IntProperty);
Console.WriteLine(ref2.IntProperty);
```

And results:

```
12
12
15
15
```